# cordova 4.3: danwilson/google-analytics-plugin throwing Cannot read property 'trackView' of undefined

Tags: cordova, google-analytics

i successfully installed the plugin with instructions at https://github.com/danwilson/google-analytics-plugin using command
`cordova plugin add https://github.com/danwilson/google-analytics-plugin.git`

below is my tracker in index.js

```
    var app = {
    // Application Constructor
    initialize: function() {
        this.bindEvents();
    },
    bindEvents: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
    },
    onDeviceReady: function() {
        app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
    },
    // Update DOM on a Received Event
    receivedEvent: function(id) {
        var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
        var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
        var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');
        listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
        receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');
        console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
// replaced with fake tracker id
        window.analytics.startTrackerWithId('UA-1234-1');
    }
};
app.initialize();
```

now i am trying to use `window.analytics.trackView('Landing')` in landing.js file, but it throws Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'trackView' of undefined

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#landing', function(){
    window.analytics.trackView('Landing');
$(document).on('click', '#guest', function() {
        event.preventDefault();
        window.location.href = "guest_search.html";
});
```

below is the head tag of my home.html where i am getting my .js files

```
<head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <!--<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">-->
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.13.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
        <script src="cordova.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/index.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/landing.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
```

This is supposed to be very easy. dont know what i am doing wrong, any suggestions?

Comment: can you confirm config.xml and cordova_plugin.js is added correctly ?

Comment: yes. i confirm. feature name UniversalAnalytics exists in both (android and ios) projects config.xml and cordova_plugins.js also exists in both projects. one point to note is, i am testing this in a simulator and when it doesnt load, i open it in the browser and see the error message in the browser console.

Comment: you can't view this is browser. it is not javascript sdk . it is Mobile SDK. one way you can do is use ios simulator and debug using safari